# Valid or not: "Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you"?

Tags: grammar

Is this valid?

> Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you.

I'd normally phrase this as:

> Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you with.

Or, alternately:

> Treat others with the same respect with which you'd want them to treat you.

Is the abbreviated version correct?

Comment: Funny - the next link I read after this was this: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13/when-is-it-appropriate-to-be-a-dick-on-skeptics-stackexchange/15#15 which has your sentence as one of the first statements :)

Answer (score 4):

Dropping the second "with" leaves me feeling that the sentence is incomplete; the structure of the sentence does not imply the preposition, and the verb "treat" can be used with other prepositions.

While I expect that your slightly-foreshortened version would be readily understood, I don't think it's good form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm for the last alternative, even though it doesn't roll off the tongue. I would also consider a reword like

> If you want others to treat you with
>   respect, treat them with the same
>   respect.

or the more famous shorter version of the original,

> Treat others as you would have them
>   treat you.

Comment: Would that not be _Treat others as you would like others to treat you_ if one paraphrases the [Golden Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Rule)

Answer (score 0):

I can’t “treat you respect.” I can treat you *with* respect, treat you respectfully, or show you respect.

(mplungian, it is not a coincidence that this awful sentence appears [hopefully fixed, by now] in the FAQ. I was unable to convince Jeff Atwood that it was wrong.)